3d rendering in JavaScript
I am trying to make a 3d physics engine in JavaScript just for fun.
The only problem is 3d rendering as I don't know how it is done so can anyone explain the idea of 3d rendering.
Here is an example of a 3d perspective cube rotating.


<style>

    *{

        margin: 0;

    }

    canvas {

        background: black;

    }

</style>

<canvas></canvas>

<script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")

    

var fov = [120 * Math.PI / 180, 90 * Math.PI / 180]



canvas.width = innerWidth

var dist = (canvas.width / 2) / Math.tan(fov[0] / 2)

canvas.height = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * dist) * 2



if (canvas.height > innerHeight) {

    canvas.height = innerHeight

    var dist = (canvas.height / 2) / Math.tan(fov[1] / 2)

    canvas.width = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * dist) * 2

}



var c = canvas.getContext("2d")



c.fillStyle = "red"

c.strokeStyle = "white"



var solids = []



function rotateX(vector, angle) {

    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    var l = Math.hypot(vector.y, vector.z)

    var cAngle = Math.atan2(vector.z, vector.y)

    cAngle += angle

    vector.y = Math.cos(cAngle) * l

    vector.z = Math.sin(cAngle) * l

}

function rotateY(vector, angle) {

    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    var l = Math.hypot(vector.x, vector.z)

    var cAngle = Math.atan2(vector.z, vector.x)

    cAngle += angle

    vector.x = Math.cos(cAngle) * l

    vector.z = Math.sin(cAngle) * l

}

function rotateZ(vector, angle) {

    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    var l = Math.hypot(vector.x, vector.y)

    var cAngle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x)

    cAngle += angle

    vector.x = Math.cos(cAngle) * l

    vector.y = Math.sin(cAngle) * l

}



class Vertex {

    constructor(x, y, z) {

        this.x = x,

        this.y = y,

        this.z = z 

    }

}



class Cube {

    constructor(pos, size) {

        this.size = size

        this.pos = pos

        this.angleX = 0

        this.angleY = 0

        this.angleZ = 30

        this.vertices = []

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(0, 0, 0))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(size, 0, 0))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(0, size, 0))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(0, 0, size))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(size, size, 0))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(size, 0, size))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(0, size, size))

        this.vertices.push(new Vertex(size, size, size))

    }

    draw() {

        this.vertices.forEach(v => {

            rotateX(v, 1)

            rotateY(v, 1)

            rotateZ(v, 1)

            var d = v.z + this.pos.z

            var width = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d) * 2

            var height = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d) * 2

            

            var x = (width / 2 - v.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width

            var y = (height / 2 - v.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height

            

            

            

            this.vertices.forEach(v2 => {

                var d2 = v2.z + this.pos.z

                var width2 = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d2) * 2

                var height2 = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d2) * 2

                

                var x2 = (width2 / 2 - v2.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width2

                var y2 = (height2 / 2 - v2.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height2

                this.vertices.forEach(v3 => {

                    if (v != v2 && v2 != v3) {

                        var d3 = v3.z + this.pos.z

                        var width3 = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d3) * 2

                        var height3 = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d3) * 2

                        

                        var x3 = (width3 / 2 - v3.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width3

                        var y3 = (height3 / 2 - v3.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height3

                        c.beginPath()

                        c.moveTo(x, y)

                        c.lineTo(x2, y2)

                        c.lineTo(x3, y3)

                        c.lineTo(x, y)

                        c.fillStyle = "red"

                        c.fill()

                        

                    }

                })

            })

        })

        this.vertices.forEach(v => {

            var d = v.z + this.pos.z

            var width = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d) * 2

            var height = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d) * 2

            

            var x = (width / 2 - v.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width

            var y = (height / 2 - v.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height

            

            

            

            this.vertices.forEach(v2 => {

                var d2 = v2.z + this.pos.z

                var width2 = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d2) * 2

                var height2 = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d2) * 2

                

                var x2 = (width2 / 2 - v2.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width2

                var y2 = (height2 / 2 - v2.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height2

                

                if (Math.round(Math.hypot(v.x - v2.x, v.y - v2.y, v.z - v2.z)) == this.size) {

                    var d2 = v2.z + this.pos.z

                    var width2 = (Math.tan(fov[0] / 2) * d2) * 2

                    var height2 = (Math.tan(fov[1] / 2) * d2) * 2

                    

                    var x2 = (width2 / 2 - v2.x - this.pos.x) * canvas.width / width2

                    var y2 = (height2 / 2 - v2.y - this.pos.y) * canvas.height / height2

                    

                    c.beginPath()

                    c.moveTo(x, y)

                    c.lineTo(x2, y2)

                    c.stroke()

                }

            })

            

            c.beginPath()

            c.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)

            c.fillStyle = "blue"

            //c.fill()

            //c.stroke()

        })

    }

}



solids.push(new Cube({x: 0, y: 0, z: 300}, 50))



function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    solids.forEach(solid => {

        solid.draw()

    })

}

animate()

I searched a lot about an article that explains this but I didn't find anything useful

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I just need to know the idea of 3d rendering and raycasting

I just need to know the idea of 3d rendering and raycasting

WebGL is the way to go for 3D, so instead of the usual context...
var Cx = C.getContext('2d');

It now becomes...
var Gl = C.getContext('webgl');

if(Gl){

 // WebGL is supported so proceed...

}

WebGL is a big and complex world which you can commence researching here...
https://devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL.html
To check if your system supports WebGL and understand more about it click here...

I know that but I want to do everything from scratch
